# Window Manager in Android Architecture

Tags: android, architecture

I'm new to Android and am learning about Android architecture. I don't understand what `WindowManager` is supposed to do.

What does window manager do in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Dianne Hackborn wrote on the android-framework mailing list:

> The window manager creates surfaces for the application, and applications
> draw directly into those surfaces without going through the window manager. ([source](https://www.mail-archive.com/android-framework@googlegroups.com/msg01699.html))

> [T]he window manager is responsible for organizing the screen,
> applications don't get to decide that.  The window manager allocates
> surfaces and decides where they go and how they are layered; it never
> touches their bits, which is up to the application. ([source](https://www.mail-archive.com/android-framework@googlegroups.com/msg01704.html))